# Set customer "exempt of vat" when order is created in backend in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, tax

I would like to add an action in woocommerce to remove the tax from orders when created in the backend and for special users as customers.

This code is working for the normal order process on the website, but not on the backend

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'remove_tax_from_user' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents', 'remove_tax_from_user' );

function remove_tax_from_user( $post_data ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $username = $woocommerce->customer->get_username();
  $user = get_user_by('login',$username);
  if($user)
  { 
    if( get_field('steuer_befreit', "user_{$user->ID}") ):
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true );
    endif;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking us to create an action for you?  If not what is your real question ?

Comment: I am looking for the right action hook basically, because I can't find. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **In backend customer needs to be "exempt of Vat" before clicking on "Add order" .**

You could try to use the hook `save_post_shop_order` that is triggered before order data is saved in backend, this way:

```
add_action( 'save_post_shop_order', 'backend_remove_tax_from_user', 50, 3 );
function backend_remove_tax_from_user( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id; // Exit if it's an autosave

    if ( $post->post_status != 'publish' )
        return $post_id; // Exit if not 'publish' post status

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_order', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id; // Exit if user is not allowed

    if( ! isset($_POST['customer_user']) ) return $post_id; // Exit

    if( $_POST['customer_user'] > 0 ){
        $customer_id = intval($_POST['customer_user']);
        if( get_field('steuer_befreit', "user_{$customer_id}") ){
            $wc_customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );
            $wc_customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

**But this will not work** and you will not be able with any exiting hook to make that work. The only way Is to make first customer exempt of vat, then you can Add an order for this customer.

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not working. I click on create order. Then I select a customer. Then I add a product and then I click on calculate. But there is still tax included. Also when I hit save first and then try again to remove the product and add again.

Comment: @Alex I have told you at the end of my answer… So I have update it to explain that at the begining. You can't make it work if the customer is not set as "exempt of Vat" **before** beginning creating the order. In your code in front end it works as you do it in cart (and in checkout too). In backend customer needs to be "exempt of Vat" before clicking on "Add order" .

Comment: thank you for explaining me and for your help. I got it now. Would you have any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: @Alex Nop, I don't. You need to think it differently may be.